# How to select data from listbox into datagrid

Tags: c#

Hi I want to select country from `ListBox` and display this country data into data grid from database.
What I'm doing wrong?

```
OpenResult();

        var selectedColumns = from SqlCeUpdatableRecord stulpelis in sqlResultSet
                              where  stulpelis["Ship Country"] = listBox1.SelectedItem 
                              select new
                              {
                                  ShipName = stulpelis["Ship Name"],
                                  ShipPostalCode = stulpelis["Ship Postal Code"],
                                  ShipCountry = stulpelis["Ship Country"]
                              };
        dataGrid1.DataSource = selectedColumns.ToList();
        dataGrid1.Update();
```

Comment: is the `= salis` just a typo (instead of `==`) or ?

Comment: I dont know i just want to get data into datagrid by slelecting country into listbox and i dont know sytacs how to do it

Comment: try check your `Ship Country` dataType, i guess it should be `int`

Comment: no its string i gues its country name like Italy USa

Comment: What happens when you run this code? Any errors?

Comment: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) C:\Users\marrum\Desktop\MyLab\MyLab\MyLab5.cs 404 42 MyLab

Comment: Change listBox1.SelectedItem to listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() and check whether error comes or not